# black bar at bottom Revmob ad android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, revmob, banner-ads

I am using revmob banner ad in my app. The problem I am facing is:
Before banner display at bottom of layout view "Black bar is showing" when i click it hides or remove from the view. I don't know why. Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Code is this

```
RevMobBanner banner;
void showBanner() {
    revmob = RevMob.start(this); // RevMob Media ID configured in the AndroidManifest.xml file
    banner = revmob.createBanner(this);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
            view.addView(banner);
        }
    });
}
```

Xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="visible">

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

showbanner()// calling from activity

Thanks.